# Is there a numpy object containing all types?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writting a unit test of a function that only accepts numpy arrays of type `numpy.uint8` and I wanted to test that I get the right exception from **all** the other types.

So I did a set like this:

```
self.supported_types = {np.uint8}
self.not_supported_types = {np.bool_,
                                    np.int8,
                                    np.int16,
                                    np.uint16,
                                    np.int32,
                                    np.uint32,
                                    np.int64,
                                    np.uint64,
                                    np.longlong,
                                    np.ulonglong,
                                    np.float16,
                                    np.float32,
                                    np.float64,
                                    np.float128,
                                    np.complex64,
                                    np.complex128,
                                    np.complex256,
                                    np.object_,
                                    np.bytes_,
                                    np.str_,
                                    np.void,
                                    np.datetime64,
                                    np.timedelta64}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to get a list with all numpy's types without writing all of them as:

```
all_types = numpy.something() # does this exist?
not_supported = all_types.remove(numpy.uint8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use `np.dtype.__subclasses__()`:

```
[x.type for x in np.dtype.__subclasses__()]
```

Output:

```
[numpy.bool_,
 numpy.int8,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.int16,
 numpy.uint16,
 numpy.int32,
 numpy.uint32,
 numpy.int64,
 numpy.uint64,
 numpy.longlong,
 numpy.ulonglong,
 numpy.float32,
 numpy.float64,
 numpy.float128,
 numpy.complex64,
 numpy.complex128,
 numpy.complex256,
 numpy.object_,
 numpy.bytes_,
 numpy.str_,
 numpy.void,
 numpy.datetime64,
 numpy.timedelta64,
 numpy.float16,
 int,
 float,
 complex]
```

In your case:

```
supported_types = {np.uint8}
not_supported_types = ({x.type for x in np.dtype.__subclasses__()}
                       - supported_types - {int, complex, float})
```

Output:

```
{numpy.bool_,
 numpy.bytes_,
 numpy.complex128,
 numpy.complex256,
 numpy.complex64,
 numpy.datetime64,
 numpy.float128,
 numpy.float16,
 numpy.float32,
 numpy.float64,
 numpy.int16,
 numpy.int32,
 numpy.int64,
 numpy.int8,
 numpy.longlong,
 numpy.object_,
 numpy.str_,
 numpy.timedelta64,
 numpy.uint16,
 numpy.uint32,
 numpy.uint64,
 numpy.ulonglong,
 numpy.void}
```

Comment: why do we need ` ... - {int, complex, float}` ?

Comment: @Ivan because int/complex/float are also numpy dtypes, it depends if you want to include them or not in the non-supported types ;)